# How to consume a Dynamics AX webservice in an external asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

http://clientdomain.com/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/inventitemgroupservice.svc

I don't Know any thing about the data  that this service is going to give me. I just had this service. Can any one tell me what is the approach I need to take with this service. Basically I want to consume this service inside an external Asp.net web application.

I can't find any tutorial on this case. Can any one point out some tutorials on this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write [some code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc652581%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) ...

The link should get you started. On the other hand it may require *some* knowledge of the system being consumed, such as: what is an [invent item group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc967378%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)?

If you do not know what the service is going to provide, you have to ask whoever set you up on the task.

Comment: The tutorial shows how to consume an external service inside AX. And I want the opposite, Consume an AX service inside as external ASP.Net website.